# ESC/POS Printing Issue on android device (HiStone HK316) - Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, printing, bluetooth, escpos

I am working on A xamarin forms app, where i need to implement bluetooth printing. I am successfully able to print on regular iOS and android devices. but on HiStone(hk316) its not printing as it should be
[image: on HiStone(hk316)]

Below is the code i've used for Printing

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(ms))
                    {
                        bw.Write(e.Initialize());
                        bw.Write(e.PrintLine("                             "));

                        bw.Write(e.CenterAlign());
                        bw.Write(e.SetStyles(PrintStyle.Bold));
                        bw.Write(e.PrintLine(GlobalVariables.Instance.Business.Business.BusinessDisplayName));

                        bw.Write(e.PrintLine(GlobalVariables.Instance.Business.Location.LocationName));

                        bw.Write(e.PrintLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}", GlobalVariables.Instance.Business.Location.Address, GlobalVariables.Instance.Business.Location.Zip)));

                        bw.Write(e.PrintLine("Phone: " + GlobalVariables.Instance.Business.Location.Phone.ToFormattedPhone()));
                        bw.Write(e.SetStyles(PrintStyle.None | PrintStyle.FontB));

                        bw.Write(e.PrintLine(string.Format("Payout#: {0}", cashDrawer.InvoiceNumber)));

                        bw.Write(e.SetStyles(PrintStyle.None | PrintStyle.FontB));
                        bw.Write(e.PrintLine(string.Format("Date: {0}   Clerk: {1}", cashDrawer.Dated.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), GlobalVariables.Instance.User.DisplayName)));

                        bw.Write(e.PrintLine(string.Format("Station: {0}   Time: {1}", GlobalVariables.Instance.Business.Register.RegisterName, cashDrawer.Dated.ToString("HH:mm:ss"))));
                        bw.Write(e.PrintLine(""));

                        bw.Write(e.LeftAlign());
                        bw.Write(e.SetStyles(PrintStyle.None | PrintStyle.FontB));
                        bw.Write(e.PrintLine(""));
                        bw.Write(e.PrintLine($"Sig:_______________________"));
                        bw.Write(e.PrintLine(""));
                        bw.Write(e.PrintLine(""));
                        bw.Write(e.PrintLine(string.Format("Amount (Cash): {0}", cashDrawer.Amount.ToString("C"))));
                        bw.Write(e.PrintLine(string.Format("Reason : {0}", cashDrawer.Reason)));
                        bw.Write(e.PrintLine(""));
                        bw.Write(e.PrintLine(""));
                        bw.Write(e.PrintLine(""));
                        bw.Write(e.PrintLine("Witness:____________________"));
                        bw.Write(e.PrintLine(""));
                        bw.Write(e.PrintLine(""));

                        bw.Write(AsciiControlChars.GroupSeparator);
                        bw.Write('V');
                        bw.Write((byte)66);
                        bw.Write((byte)3);

                        bw.Flush();

                        ms.Position = 0;
                        var sr = new StreamReader(ms);
                        var str = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(str);
                        var bytesToPrint = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str).ToArray();
                        if (printerType == PrinterType.Bluetooth)
                        {
                            var res = await DependencyService.Get<IBlueToothService>().ConnectAndPrintAsync(bytesToPrint);
                        }
                        else if (printerType == PrinterType.Network)
                        {
                            DependencyService.Get<IPrintService>().PrintOverNetwork(bytesToPrint);
                        }

                        bw.Finish();
                    }
                }
```

I have used Shiny plugin for bluetooth connection. Thanks

Comment: Could you please describe further what happens and what you expect instead?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan thanx for you reply, the problem is reciept not printing correctly on a particular device(histone hk316)

Comment: I understand. But you are only showing one image and I don't know wether this is a correct or incorrect print and what the other one should look like.

Comment: are you saying that a specific Android device, using the SAME printer as other devices, works incorrectly?

Comment: yes! @Jason. It looks lite Bluetooth problem...